Что делает Bitmap.LockBits если PixelFormat указанный в вызове отличается от указанного в Bitmap?
Что делает Bitmap.LockBits если PixelFormat указанный в вызове отличается от указанного в Bitmap?

В этом случае конверсия происходит в недрах библиотеки GDI+. Вероятно даже с использованием ресурсов видеокарты, поэтому происходит весьма быстро.
Это потребляет дополнительную память и процессорное время на маршаллинг данных туда-обратно при локе-анлоке.
